# Simplex method and basic solutions

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

[image]

I have put this into the form

$0.5x_1 + 0.25x_2 + x_3=6$

$-x_1 - 3x_2 + x_4=-2$

$x_1 + x_2 = 10$

Is this correct? If so, how do I find a basic solution so that I can begin the simplex algorithm?

Comment: i have computed $2x_1+3x_2\geq 20$ and the equalsign holds if $x_1=10,x_2=0$

Comment: @Amzoti I got $x_5=6, x_6=2, x_7=10$?

Answer (score 0):

The system of linear equations in the question *can't* help finding a basic feasible solution since artificial variables $x_5, x_6 \ge 0$ are missed in the second and third constraints.

$0.5x_1 + 0.25x_2 + x_3=6$

$-x_1 - 3x_2 + x_4 + x_5=-2$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_6 = 10$

To find a basic feasible solution to the *original* LP, we use the [two-phase simplex method](http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/Two-phase_Method_Example).

To start with phase I, consider $\min(x_5 + x_6)$ with the above constraints.  This can be done with simplex algorithm.  As @Dr.SonnhardGraubner points out, this LP has a basic optimal feasible solution $x_1 = 10, x_2 = 0, \dots, x_5 = x_6 = 0$.  (You may end up with *another* feasible solution.)  The artificial variables vanish, so we have a basic feasible solution to the original LP.